# RequireJs optimal way to load modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

My app structure is:

```
**module1**
page1.html
module2.js
**module2**
page2.html
module2.js
```

I trty solve problem - find best way to 'require modules'
My solution:
In page1.html

include require.js

```
<script>
require.config ...
require([page1])
</script>
```

It's optimal way to load modules ?

Comment: What are the different ways available. I know only this one. I assume that's optimal as long as you are using requireJS..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go the whole nine yards on optimization, have a look at [R.js optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html), which is part of Require.js.

R.js will group modules in bundles, so that you can still do multiple `require()` calls and not do multiple HTTP requests.

For instance, if you have 3 modules to be required during page-load time, then you can use R.js to create a bundle containing those 3 modules (automatically including all their dependencies as well).

However, if you have more modules to be lazy-loaded later in the page (let's say, you want some module to be loaded only after the user clicks on a button), then you need to remember to not include those modules on your main bundle, and instead create bundles specific for the lazy-loadable modules.